# VHDL-2008 Testbench: best way to invoke procedures from a different hierarchy level of the design?

Tags: vhdl

```
     entity bram;  ... end entity;  
     architecture behavioral of bram is... begin end architecture;
```

Let's say I have a VHDL Architecture that models a Block Ram, and this Architecture has two procedures stores inside, one for writing to the memory, and one for reading from the memory.  and I have 3 of these block ram models instantiated in by testbench like this:

```
":testbench:bram_1"    
":testbench:bram_2"    
":testbench:bram_3"
```

What's the best way to invoke a procedures from a a different hierarchy level of the design?

Let's say, I'm at another level of the testbench called testcase, example:

```
     entity testcase;  ... end entity;  
     architecture behavioral of testcase is... begin end architecture;
```

with hierachy:

```
":testbench:testcase"
```

Now inside of the testcase architecture i want to call these procedures stored in the 3 instances of bram 1, 2, and 3, something like this:

```
:testbench:bram_1:write (X"FFFF", X"FFFF");
:testbench:bram_2:read  (X"FFFF", X"FFFF");    
:testbench:bram_3:write (X"FFFF", X"FFFF");
```

Can I do something similar to this in VHDL in any of its modern flavors?  For Example, In VHDL-2008, is it possible to achieve a similar effect as this?

The reason why I'm asking is because Verilog-95 has allowed you to do this for over 25 years... and I wanted to convert a Verilog-95 testbench that does exactly this to stimulate the design without massively restructuring the testbench for VHDL...

Consider this simple Verilog-2001 Example of what I would like to be able to do in VHDL-2008:

```
module sim_top_ctrl;

wire           sys_clk;
wire           sys_rst_n;

//------------------------------------------------
// Generate Simulation clock
//------------------------------------------------
sim_genclk #(
   .MHZ(100.0)
) 
genclk(
   .o_clk    (sys_clk),
   .o_rstn   (sys_rst_n)
);


//====================================
// Testcase
//==================================== 

initial begin : testcase
    integer i;
    
    genclk.reset();
    genclk.step(10);
    
    // Enable Video Buffer
    genclk.step(10);

    // Send Written Buffer Address to GPU
    for(i=0; i < 100; i=i+1) begin
        genclk.step(20);
    end

    $stop; 
end
```

```
module sim_genclk #(
   parameter real MHZ = 100.0
) (
   output reg  o_clk,
   output reg  o_rstn
);

localparam real PERIOD_NS       = (1/MHZ) * 1000.0;
localparam real HALF_PERIOD_NS  = PERIOD_NS / 2.0;

initial begin
   o_clk = 0;
   forever begin
       #HALF_PERIOD_NS o_clk = !o_clk;
   end
end

initial begin
    o_rstn = 1'b0;
    repeat(30) @(posedge o_clk);
    o_rstn = 1'b1;  
end


task reset;
begin
    $display("%m waiting reset");
    wait(o_rstn == 1'b1);
    @(posedge o_clk);
    #1;
    $display("%m reset released");      
end endtask


task step;
    input   [31:0] cycle;
begin
    
    $display("%m STEP cycles:%0d", cycle);
    
    repeat(cycle) begin
        @(posedge o_clk); #1;
    end

end endtask



endmodule
```

Any Ideas on how to achieve a similar effect in VHDL to invoke procedures in a different hierarchy level?

Comment: Vhdl2008 can only use external names to objects. You cannot access internal procedures etc. But you might want to consider protected types. They can have their own methods, and you can access the objects via external names and call their methods.

Comment: Its not a bad idea.. I could pass a protected  object into an architecture that has read and write functions that write commands to some type of queue... then in the architecture read this queue using the protected object passed into the architecture?  I've never seen this done before... maybe somebody has an example?  maybe you don't need a queue. because i want I want the method to block until internal procedure is finished instead of the architecture.... what i need is a signally mechanism between externally exposed methods of the object and internal procedure of the architecture...

Comment: Some good news and bad news.  Good news is I do pretty much exactly what you describe in my in house axi verification ip. Bad news is that waiting and blocking in protected types is illegal. So I have a protected type in an entity where a process pulls the transactions out of it. I post them in from the testbench via an external names alias. Osvvm scoreboard can be used as a generic queue.

Comment: And a note,  waiting and blocking in protected types still illegal in vhdl2019. I've requested the feature for a future revision.

Comment: But you might need an overall rethink. Stuff you do in verilog won't map 1to1 to vhdl. What you want to do is perfectly possible in vhdl, but you would usually do such things at the testbench level rather than digging around in the hierarchy.

Comment: OSVVM has a memory modeling package.   You can get these from GitHub at:  https://github.com/OSVVM/OsvvmLibraries.   Documentation is in the documentation repository.   With the protected type, you can access the protected type as an external name.   It is pretty basic VHDL-2008 stuff that SynthWorks covers in our training classes.   The memory models support FileReadH and FileReadB which read a file in a format that is upward compatible with Verilog.

Comment: If you are going to request features for VHDL 2020+, The easist solution would be to relax the rules for hierarchical references in VHDL to exactly follow the rules in Verilog 
 by allowing procedure to be triggered using a hierarchical reference to them...These days, there is really only one simulator engine anyways... VHDL simulators are really just SystemVerilog simulators with different code translator on the front because EDA companies are lazy... i'm sure the standards people could easily expose that hierarchical procedure reference feature in SystemVerilog to VHDL translation layer...